# NPM run dev error after requiring Tailwind CSS

Tags: node.js, laravel

I'm just dipping my toes into using Laravel for the first time, and I've had many issues so far. I've figured them out myself so far, but this one is driving me crazy!

After adding the line `require('tailwindcss')` in my webpack.mix.js file, I keep getting the following error when I run.

```
npm run dev
```

```
✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 452.52ms

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at getTailwindConfig (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:81:62)
    at /home/timothy/blog/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:124:92
    at /home/timothy/blog/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:41:11
    at plugins (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:20:104)
    at LazyResult.runOnRoot (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:339:16)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:393:26)
    at LazyResult.async (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
    at LazyResult.then (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)
    at processResult (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:19)
    at /home/timothy/blog/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:853:5
    at /home/timothy/blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /home/timothy/blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (/home/timothy/blog/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:142:7)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/timothy/.npm/_logs/2022-01-18T04_24_37_451Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/timothy/.npm/_logs/2022-01-18T04_24_37_460Z-debug.log
```

I've looked into my version of Node.js and PostCSS being an issue, as my version of node.js has been an issue that caused other problems I've had so far, but those two seem fine. If it matters, this is a Laravel project created with Composer on Ubuntu 20.04 with Laravel installer 4.2.9.

Comment: Do you have `tailwind.config.js` file on root directory?

Comment: Like in the root directory of my Laravel project?

Comment: Yes, if you follow the official doc it will give you a command to generate the file `npx tailwindcss init`

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this comman. Tailwind config file is missing.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer 
npx tailwindcss init
```

Comment: youre mentioning the config file is missing. what woukd it look like?

Comment: @Fiehra, if you run the above command, you will see a file has been created called tailwind.config.js.
You will get more details about config file [there](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration).